# node kafka consumer group not receiving message when broker down

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a topic in kafka as **`internal`**. I have created the topic using the below command

```
/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh 
     --create --zookeeper zookeeper:2181 
     --replication-factor 3 -partitions 6 
     --topic internal
```

I need to consume all the message in three different node servers. So I am using [kafka-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/kafka-node) module as a consumer group with different consumer name. I have created a consumer group name called `group1`, `group2`, `group3`.

Everything working fine, I can consume all the messages in all consumers.

But when any broker is down, the consumer is not getting any message. When I list all the consumer groups, it does not showing the specific group ID.

(e.g) If `nodeserver 1` is down there is no group available in broker called `group1`

Even if I restart the node server, it does not create any group in broker and not consuming any messages in the respective node server. But when the broker is up, and the node server is restarted, it is creating a group in broker and the node server can receive message.

`consumer.js`

```
const options = {
  kafkaHost: process.env.KAFKA_HOST, 
  groupId: group_id, //group1 (or) group2 (or) group3
  autoCommit: true,
  sessionTimeout: 15000,
  protocol: ['roundrobin'],
  fromOffset: 'latest',
  outOfRangeOffset: 'earliest',
  migrateHLC: false,
  migrateRolling: true,
  fetchMaxBytes: 1024 * 1024 * 10,
  commitOffsetsOnFirstJoin: true,
  onRebalance: (isAlreadyMember, callback) => {
      log.info({"ALREADY_MEMBER_isAlreadyMember": isAlreadyMember});
      callback();
  }
};

const consumerGroup = new ConsumerGroup(options, process.env.KAFKA_TOPIC);

// On receiving message
consumerGroup.on("message", handMessage); //handMessage is where the message has been handled

// On error receiving message
consumerGroup.on('error', function(err) {
    log.debug({"type": "KAFKA_CONSUMER_ERROR", "msg": err});
});
// On error receiving message
consumerGroup.on('offsetOutOfRange', function(err) {
    log.debug({"type": "KAFKA_CONSUMER_RANGE_ERROR", "msg": err});
});
```

---

***UPDATE - 1***

Even if I updated `offsets.topic.replication.factor` as `2` or `3`, I am having the same issue. When I any broker is down, the respective node server is not consuming the message. And also when I show list of groups in broker, it shows only `group2` and `group3`. But the `group1` is not there when the `broker1` is down. Even if I restart the node consumer, the `group1` is not getting created.

`server.properties`

```
broker.id=1
listeners=INSIDE://:9092,OUTSIDE://:9094
advertised.listeners=INSIDE://:9092,OUTSIDE://:9094
listener.security.protocol.map=INSIDE:PLAINTEXT,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT
num.network.threads=3
num.io.threads=8
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
log.dirs=/kafka/kafka-logs-d3f14c9ddf0a
num.partitions=1
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1
offsets.topic.replication.factor=3
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=3
transaction.state.log.min.isr=2
log.retention.hours=168
log.segment.bytes=1073741824
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
zookeeper.connect=zookeeper1:2181,zookeeper2:2181,zookeeper3:2181
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=16000
group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0
inter.broker.listener.name=INSIDE
advertised.port=9094
port=9092
auto.create.topics.enable=false
```

---

***UPDATE - 2***

When the broker is down, the group coordinator is getting deleted and it is not automatically re-electing.

Can you guys tell me what I did wrong? Or is there anything else I need to update?

Comment: Please show your Kafka server properties file... What is the replication factor of the consumer offsets topic?

Comment: Updated server.properties file. Please check.

Comment: Show the description of `__consumer_offsets` topic as well

Comment: The `__consumer_offsets` topic is having replication factor of 1 only

Comment: Exactly - As I mentioned in my answer, you need to manually increase it for your cluster to be highly available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Even if I updated `offsets.topic.replication.factor` as 2 or 3, I am having the same issue. When I any broker is down, the respective node server is not consuming the message

After the offsets topic is created, changing this property doesn't do anything.

If it *was* set to one, then you now need [to manually increase it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43518389/2308683)

Comment: Actually I have deleted the topic and re-created it, still no luck.

Comment: Outside of a test scenario, that isn't a good idea, but I assume you did `--replication-factor` more than 1?

Comment: Whenever I try to test the scenario, I'll delete the topic and re-create the topic using this command `/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper zookeeper:2181 --replication-factor 3 -partitions 6 --topic internal`

Comment: `internal`?? The topic needs to be `__consumer_offsets`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is at-least Kafka 1.x, some changes are required regarding the HA for `internal` Kafka topics. Consider the following snippet from `server.properties`. The default values for replication are set to 1. In your case, for 3 brokers, setting these to 2 might be a good place to start.

```
# The replication factor for the group metadata internal topics "__consumer_offsets" and "__transaction_state"
# For anything other than development testing, a value greater than 1 is recommended for to ensure availability such as 3.
offsets.topic.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=1
```

**Addition**

As per my understanding, each consumer-group has its group coordinator. So, if there are multiple groups consuming from a topic, there **can** be multiple coordinators (different brokers) for that topic. A broker can act as a `group coordinator` for multiple consumer groups. But for a consumer-group there's only one broker which acts as coordinator. For a particular consumer group we can check which broker is the coordinator using this command:

```
./kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server <broker-host>:9092 --describe --group <consumer-group> --state
```

If a coordinator fails, some other broker is chosen as the coordinator. The failover strategy is explained in detail [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Kafka+Detailed+Consumer+Coordinator+Design#KafkaDetailedConsumerCoordinatorDesign-10.OnCoordinatorFailover) in section 10.

Comment: Even if I updated offsets.topic.replication.factor as 2 or 3, I am having the same issue. When any broker is down, the respective node server is not consuming the message

Comment: Can you please create a new topic with the same parameters, and try it out on that one?

Comment: Yes I did, but no luck

Comment: does a broker will have only one consumer group per topic? or it can have multiple consumer group per topic?

Comment: I got your point. But when one broker is deleted, the respective consumer group is not listed in available brokers. The group coordinator is not getting elected as other two brokers are still available.

Comment: Even if I restart my node kafka consumer with same group name, the group name is not getting created.