# How to update replication-factors for created topic?

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

We have created kafka topics with default `replication-factor` as 1, to update this we have added property `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.replication-factor: 3` in application.yaml which has no reflect on created topics in kafka.

spring cloud stream version used is Germantown.SR1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The underlying `AdminClient` used by the binder and Spring for Apache Kafka to create/modify topics does not support changing the replication factor.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37960767/how-to-change-the-number-of-replicas-of-a-kafka-topic/43518389#43518389) to see how to do it with command-line tools (`kafka-reassign-partitions`).