# Kafka - set min ISR based on topics' prefix

Tags: apache-kafka

I have following problem to solve. Do You Guys know mechanism that would allow set different min ISR value based on topic prefix? For example topics created with prefix `app-*` would have min ISR factor value set to 2, `logs-*` equal to 1 but value for `core-*` would be 4.

---

#### Solution proposal

`min.insync.replicas.per.topic=topic_name_1:value,topic_name_2:value` looks almost as a solution but unfortunately it is shadowed when `min.insync.replicas` is also present in `kafka.properties`. So I will explore if there is solution to combine those two props.
[source](https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/kafka/latest/topics/kafka_ha.html)

Verifying min ISR value using

```sh
./kafka-configs.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 \
 --entity-type topics --entity-name $TOPIC --describe --all
```

Comment: How are you creating topics? There's plenty of tooling outside of the kafka-topics command that you can programmatically create this. The Terraform Kafka provider, for example, would just be a variable change

Comment: @OneCricketeer - `auto.create.topics.enable` is set to true and custom producers are writing to kafka cluster

Answer (score 3):

***Edit: In order to avoid 80's style solutions (such as shown in this answer), please take a look at Dirk's answer.***

*I just love bash/sh*

---

For already created topics, you'd have to execute a [partition reassignment operation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43518389/2148953).

**If you wish to control the `ISR` for newly created topics**, you could wrap the `kafka-topics.sh` script in a new script, lets call it **`createTopics.sh`**:

```
#!/bin/bash
isr=0

if [[ $1 = \logs* ]]; then
        isr=1
elif  [[ $1 = \app* ]]; then
        isr=2
elif  [[ $1 = \core* ]]; then
        isr=4
fi

/bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --topic $1 --replication-factor $isr \
                     --partitions $3  --bootstrap-server $2
```

- `$1` - **topic name**
- `$2` - bootstrap-server
- `$3` - partitions

For example:

```
  ./createTopics.sh apps-topic localhost:9092 1 && \
  ./createTopics.sh core-topic localhost:9092 1
```

This would create two new topics with their respective replication-factor:

- **`apps-topic`** > `ISR` = **2**.
- **`core-topic`** > `ISR` = **4**.

*(max ISR value, assuming all replicas are in-sync)*

---

The script would also validate the creation of new topics, as it wouldn't create any topic which name doesn't start with one of these: *logs / app / core*. Kafka would show an error,  `Replication factor must be larger than 0`.

You could change this behaviour in order to allow different topic prefixes, by setting the default isr value at the start of the script different than 0: `isr=1`, for example. This would lead to:

```
#!/bin/bash
isr=1

if  [[ $1 = \app* ]]; then
       isr=2
elif  [[ $1 = \core* ]]; then
       isr=4
fi

/bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --topic $1 --replication-factor $isr \
                     --partitions $3  --bootstrap-server $2
```

Comment: Thanks for Your answer, I believe that it might work but I would like to bootstrap cluster using config file instead of running custom script

Comment: @MichałDygas You're more than welcome, for your use case, I believe you could find some use of the kafkactl tool (as you said, it looks neat).I just love bash, but this solution is very error-prone on production...just a primitive way to solve this. More than a solution, a temporal fix. But I had a good time writting it, really!

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [kafkactl](https://github.com/deviceinsight/kafkactl) for this:

```sh
# first run with --validate-only to see what kafkactl will do
kafkactl get topics -o compact | grep '^app.*'  | xargs -i echo "echo Topic: {};kafkactl alter topic {} --replication-factor 2 --validate-only" | sh
kafkactl get topics -o compact | grep '^log.*'  | xargs -i echo "echo Topic: {};kafkactl alter topic {} --replication-factor 1 --validate-only" | sh
kafkactl get topics -o compact | grep '^core.*' | xargs -i echo "echo Topic: {};kafkactl alter topic {} --replication-factor 4 --validate-only" | sh

# then do the replica reassignment
kafkactl get topics -o compact | grep '^app.*'  | xargs -i echo "echo Topic: {};kafkactl alter topic {} --replication-factor 2" | sh
kafkactl get topics -o compact | grep '^log.*'  | xargs -i echo "echo Topic: {};kafkactl alter topic {} --replication-factor 1" | sh
kafkactl get topics -o compact | grep '^core.*' | xargs -i echo "echo Topic: {};kafkactl alter topic {} --replication-factor 4" | sh
```

Note that the Kafka API that kafkactl is using for this is only available for Kafka ≥ 2.4.0.

Disclaimer: I am contributor to this project

Comment: Hello @Dirk, `kafkactl` looks neat and believe me I will try using this tool. But I was looking for config file, that would provide this functionality without unnecessary cmd calls.