# Apache Kafka partition leader distribution on brokers

Tags: apache-kafka

We have a Apache Kafka 3 node Cluster and around 10 topics with varying partitions for each topic. I see always one of the broker node contains leader partition of all topics and due to this CPU usage of the the server is always 70 % and above.  Is there any configuration to tune the partition leader spreading across all brokers? Please advice.

Comment: Yes, you can assign partitions manually , check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37960767/how-to-change-the-number-of-replicas-of-a-kafka-topic

Comment: I am not looking for partition reassignment, but was wondering why all leader partition are centered around one broker rather spread across other 2 brokers.