# kafka-reassign-partitions --generate for topic __commit_offsets gives me strange result: partition replica only on one broker anyway

Tags: apache-kafka, replication

kafka-reassign-partitions --generate for topic __commit_offsets gives me strange result: partition replica only on one broker anyway, but expected 3 replicas for each partition.

I do the following:

```
test@kafka-1:~/Kafka-Docker$ sudo docker exec -it broker bash
[appuser@broker ~]$ echo '{"version":1, "topics":[{"topic":"__consumer_offsets"}]}' > topics-to-move.json
[appuser@broker ~]$ kafka-reassign-partitions --zookeeper $KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT --topics-to-move-json-file topics-to-move.json --broker-list "1,2,3" --generate
Warning: --zookeeper is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version of Kafka.
Current partition replica assignment
{"version":1,"partitions":[{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":0,"replicas":[1],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":1,"replicas":[1],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":2,"replicas":[1],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":3,"replicas":[1],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":4,"replicas":[1],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":5,"replicas":[1],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":6,"replicas":[1],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":7,"replicas":[1],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":8,"replicas":[1],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":9,"replicas":[1],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":10,"replicas":[1],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":11,"replicas":[1],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":12,"replicas":[1],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":13,"replicas":[1],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":14,"replicas":[1],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":15,"replicas":[1],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":16,"replicas":[1],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":17,"replicas":[1],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":18,"replicas":[1],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":19,"replicas":[1],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":20,"replicas":[1],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":21,"replicas":[1],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":22,"replicas":[1],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":23,"replicas":[1],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":24,"replicas":[1],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":25,"replicas":[1],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":26,"replicas":[1],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":27,"replicas":[1],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":28,"replicas":[1],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":29,"replicas":[1],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":30,"replicas":[1],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":31,"replicas":[1],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":32,"replicas":[1],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":33,"replicas":[1],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":34,"replicas":[1],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":35,"replicas":[1],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":36,"replicas":[1],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":37,"replicas":[1],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":38,"replicas":[1],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":39,"replicas":[1],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":40,"replicas":[1],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":41,"replicas":[1],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":42,"replicas":[1],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":43,"replicas":[1],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":44,"replicas":[1],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":45,"replicas":[1],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":46,"replicas":[1],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":47,"replicas":[1],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":48,"replicas":[1],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":49,"replicas":[1],"log_dirs":["any"]}]}

Proposed partition reassignment configuration
{"version":1,"partitions":[{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":0,"replicas":[1],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":1,"replicas":[2],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":2,"replicas":[3],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":3,"replicas":[1],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":4,"replicas":[2],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":5,"replicas":[3],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":6,"replicas":[1],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":7,"replicas":[2],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":8,"replicas":[3],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":9,"replicas":[1],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":10,"replicas":[2],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":11,"replicas":[3],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":12,"replicas":[1],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":13,"replicas":[2],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":14,"replicas":[3],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":15,"replicas":[1],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":16,"replicas":[2],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":17,"replicas":[3],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":18,"replicas":[1],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":19,"replicas":[2],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":20,"replicas":[3],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":21,"replicas":[1],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":22,"replicas":[2],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":23,"replicas":[3],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":24,"replicas":[1],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":25,"replicas":[2],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":26,"replicas":[3],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":27,"replicas":[1],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":28,"replicas":[2],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":29,"replicas":[3],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":30,"replicas":[1],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":31,"replicas":[2],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":32,"replicas":[3],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":33,"replicas":[1],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":34,"replicas":[2],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":35,"replicas":[3],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":36,"replicas":[1],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":37,"replicas":[2],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":38,"replicas":[3],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":39,"replicas":[1],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":40,"replicas":[2],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":41,"replicas":[3],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":42,"replicas":[1],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":43,"replicas":[2],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":44,"replicas":[3],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":45,"replicas":[1],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":46,"replicas":[2],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":47,"replicas":[3],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":48,"replicas":[1],"log_dirs":["any"]},{"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":49,"replicas":[2],"log_dirs":["any"]}]}
[appuser@broker ~]$
```

I see that zookeepers option is deprecated so I also tried this (with the same result):

```
kafka-reassign-partitions --bootstrap-server kafka-1:9092  --topics-to-move-json-file topics-to-move.json --broker-list "1,2,3" --generate
```

**PROBLEM:**

As you may see, "Current partition replica assignment" has "replicas: [1]" only and "Proposed partition reassignment configuration" has "replicas: [1]" or "replicas: [2]" or "replicas: [3]" for each partition.

But for "Proposed partition reassignment configuration" it expected to be something like "replicas: [1,2,3]" or "replicas: [2,3,1]" and so on for redudancy of __commit_offsets across 3 brokers.

**Why only one replica for each partiotion is bound to one broker only? Why 3 replicas for each partition are not spreaded across 3 brokers?**

Example of good topic (but it has only one partition) replicated across all 3 brokers, it looks this way:

```
{"version":1,"partitions":[{"topic":"test_topic","partition":0,"replicas":[1,2,3],"log_dirs":["any","any","any"]}]}
```

**My setup:**
3 VMs 192.168.1.11, .12 and.13 each has zookeeper and broker, zookeepers connected to quorum ok - I see only one leader through its REST API (for example http://192.168.1.11:4888/commands/stats same for .12 and .13 IPs) and that's good. Also tested switch off one of zookeepers and new leader elected in that case - works perfect.

Example of docker-compose.yml for 192.168.1.11 VM is (other similar):

```
version: '3.7'

x-zoo: &zoo "kafka-1:2888:3888;kafka-2:2888:3888;kafka-3:2888:3888"
x-kafkaZookeepers: &kafkaZookeepers "kafka-1:2181,kafka-2:2181,kafka-3:2181"
x-kafkaBrokers: &kafkaBrokers "kafka-1:9092,kafka-2:9092,kafka-3:9092"

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:6.2.1
    hostname: zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
      - "2888:2888"
      - "3888:3888"
      - "4888:8080"
    extra_hosts:
      - "kafka-1:192.168.1.11"
      - "kafka-2:192.168.1.12"
      - "kafka-3:192.168.1.13"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 1
      ZOOKEEPER_QUORUM_LISTEN_ON_ALL_IPS: 'true'
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_PEER_PORT: 2888
      ZOOKEEPER_LEADER_PORT: 3888
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
      ZOOKEEPER_INIT_LIMIT: 5
      ZOOKEEPER_SYNC_LIMIT: 2
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS: *zoo
    volumes:
      - ./kafka-data/zookeeper:/var/lib/zookeeper/data
      - ./kafka-data/zookeeper-logs:/var/lib/zookeeper/log
    networks:
      - mynet

  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:6.2.1
    hostname: broker
    container_name: broker
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    extra_hosts:
      - "kafka-1:192.168.1.11"
      - "kafka-2:192.168.1.12"
      - "kafka-3:192.168.1.13"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: OUTSIDE://0.0.0.0:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: OUTSIDE://192.168.1.11:9092
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: OUTSIDE
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: *kafkaZookeepers
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 3
      KAFKA_DEFAULT_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 3
      KAFKA_LOG_MESSAGE_TIMESTAMP_TYPE: 'LogAppendTime'
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      KAFKA_CONNECTIONS_MAX_IDLE_MS: 31536000000 # 1 year
    volumes:
      - ./kafka-data/kafka:/var/lib/kafka/data
    networks:
      - mynet

networks:
  mynet:
    driver: bridge
```

It was set up first with:

1. KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
2. KAFKA_DEFAULT_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1

Then +2 other setups on .12 and .13 VMs added (of course with different **ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID** and **KAFKA_BROKER_ID**) and on each **KAFKA_DEFAULT_REPLICATION_FACTOR** and **KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR** changed from 1 to 3.

Then new topics created OK with replication factor 3, also I was able easily change replication factor to 3 for my existing non-system topics, but except topic __commit_offsets of cource - it need to be reassigned using kafka-reassign-partitions command line tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR` changed from 1 to 3.

The offsets topic only gets created on a brand new cluster. It will not retroactively get updated if you modify `offsets.topic.replication.factor`.

> new topics created OK with replication factor 3

Correct, however, any topic created **before** you increased `default.replication.factor` will also only have one replica.

Reassign partition tool doesn't take into account your server properties. You either need a different tool or manually place the replicas yourself. - [How to change the number of replicas of a Kafka topic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37960767/how-to-change-the-number-of-replicas-of-a-kafka-topic)

Comment: I really surprized that it's necesary to edit "Proposed partition reassignment configuration" and set "replicas: [1,2,3]" manually.
Also I saw in examples that for each partition brokers in repicas are shifted/reordered, for example for "partition: 0" it "replicas: [1,2,3]", then for "partition: 1" it "replicas: [2,3,1]", then for "partition: 2" it "replicas: [3,2,1]" ans so on - how it "calculated" then? Or it's ok just to set "replicas: [1,2,3]" for every partition?

Comment: I cannot recall if the order really matters, but yeah, you need to manually place them. It just returns whatever information is in Zookeeper when you query for the partition placement. Doesn't sort it