# Kafka replication issue

Tags: apache-kafka, replication

I am using a 3 broker kafka.
If I stop the third node: no problem, I can consume LOGS from node 1 or 2.
If I stop the second node : no problem, I can consume LOGS from node 1 or 3.
If I stop the first node : I am not able to consume anything.

When I restart kafka-runner service . Logs are here and was wrote properly.

my topic configuration is:
Topic: log_topic    TopicId: xxx    PartitionCount: 32  ReplicationFactor: 3    Configs: segment.bytes=1073741824,retention.ms=7200000
Topic: log_topic    Partition: 0    Leader: 2   Replicas: 1,2,3 Isr: 2,3,1
Topic: log_topic    Partition: 1    Leader: 2   Replicas: 1,2,3 Isr: 2,3,1
Topic: log_topic    Partition: 2    Leader: 2   Replicas: 1,2,3 Isr: 2,3,1
Topic: log_topic    Partition: 3    Leader: 2   Replicas: 1,2,3 Isr: 2,3,1
Topic: log_topic    Partition: 4    Leader: 2   Replicas: 1,2,3 Isr: 2,3,1
Topic: log_topic    Partition: 5    Leader: 2   Replicas: 1,2,3 Isr: 2,3,1
Topic: log_topic    Partition: 6    Leader: 2   Replicas: 1,2,3 Isr: 2,3,1
Topic: log_topic    Partition: 7    Leader: 2   Replicas: 1,2,3 Isr: 2,3,1
Topic: log_topic    Partition: 8    Leader: 2   Replicas: 1,2,3 Isr: 2,3,1
Topic: log_topic    Partition: 9    Leader: 2   Replicas: 1,2,3 Isr: 2,3,1
Topic: log_topic    Partition: 10   Leader: 2   Replicas: 2,3,1 Isr: 2,3,1
Topic: log_topic    Partition: 11   Leader: 3   Replicas: 3,1,2 Isr: 2,3,1
Topic: log_topic    Partition: 12   Leader: 3   Replicas: 1,3,2 Isr: 2,3,1
Topic: log_topic    Partition: 13   Leader: 2   Replicas: 2,1,3 Isr: 2,3,1
Topic: log_topic    Partition: 14   Leader: 3   Replicas: 3,2,1 Isr: 2,3,1
Topic: log_topic    Partition: 15   Leader: 2   Replicas: 1,2,3 Isr: 2,3,1
Topic: log_topic    Partition: 16   Leader: 2   Replicas: 2,3,1 Isr: 2,3,1
Topic: log_topic    Partition: 17   Leader: 3   Replicas: 3,1,2 Isr: 2,3,1
Topic: log_topic    Partition: 18   Leader: 3   Replicas: 1,3,2 Isr: 2,3,1
Topic: log_topic    Partition: 19   Leader: 2   Replicas: 2,1,3 Isr: 2,3,1
Topic: log_topic    Partition: 20   Leader: 3   Replicas: 3,2,1 Isr: 2,3,1
Topic: log_topic    Partition: 21   Leader: 2   Replicas: 1,2,3 Isr: 2,3,1
Topic: log_topic    Partition: 22   Leader: 2   Replicas: 2,3,1 Isr: 2,3,1
Topic: log_topic    Partition: 23   Leader: 3   Replicas: 3,1,2 Isr: 2,3,1
Topic: log_topic    Partition: 24   Leader: 3   Replicas: 1,3,2 Isr: 2,3,1
Topic: log_topic    Partition: 25   Leader: 2   Replicas: 2,1,3 Isr: 2,3,1
Topic: log_topic    Partition: 26   Leader: 3   Replicas: 3,2,1 Isr: 2,3,1
Topic: log_topic    Partition: 27   Leader: 2   Replicas: 1,2,3 Isr: 2,3,1
Topic: log_topic    Partition: 28   Leader: 2   Replicas: 2,3,1 Isr: 2,3,1
Topic: log_topic    Partition: 29   Leader: 3   Replicas: 3,1,2 Isr: 2,3,1
Topic: log_topic    Partition: 30   Leader: 3   Replicas: 1,3,2 Isr: 2,3,1
Topic: log_topic    Partition: 31   Leader: 2   Replicas: 2,1,3 Isr: 2,3,1

When I stop leader node. leader changes properly.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a configuration issue with the **__consumer_offsets** topic.

> _consumer_offsets is used to store information about committed offsets for each topic:partition per group of consumers (groupID)

Whenever a consumer in a group reads data from kafka, it periodically stores the information on the point till the data is read in a special topic called __consumer_offsets. This is done so that the consumer can resume from its last position in case of failure.

**Issue**

The replication factor for __consumer_offsets topic would have been set to 1 and all the partitions for the topic would also be present in broker 1.

You can describe the __consumer_offsets topic to verify above.
If this is the case, then the easiest way to resolve the issue would be to delete the __consumer_offsets topic and recreate it with the desired replication factor.

If deletion is not an option, then following the instructions in the thread below

[How to change the number of replicas of a Kafka topic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37960767/how-to-change-the-number-of-replicas-of-a-kafka-topic)

Comment: Fixed: __consumer_offsets was setup to one and was on first node. I will check who to define this in server properties. I changed attribute with execute command. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your **`__consumer_offsets` topic** has three replicas and is not only hosted on broker 1. By default it only has 1 replica, as established in `server.properties`